# Configuring dmypy to check only some files with vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy

I'm using mypy deamon with vscode (and [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matangover.mypy)), and I wish to make it check only some of the files in my project.

In my `pyproject.toml`, I have mypy configured with something like this:

```
[tool.mypy]
scripts_are_modules = true
show_traceback = true
files = [
    "server/**/*_some_files.py"
]
```

According to the [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-files), it should work and the desired behavior is that only `.py` files under the `server` directory should be checked, but this doesn't work.

Running it with vscode shows that files that do not match the configurations are still checked

```
[69] Check workspace: /home/pig208/myproject
[69] Using config file: pyproject.toml
[69] Received python path from Python extension: /home/pig208/myproject/.venv/bin/python
[69] Running dmypy in folder /home/pig208/myproject
/home/pig208/myproject/.venv/bin/python -m mypy.dmypy --status-file /home/pig208/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/640660fb9d95e4f81c730061907f1d4c/matangover.mypy/dmypy-d1f12cdee9d0591a310a9c4402749ab59684e6e7.json run --log-file /home/pig208/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/640660fb9d95e4f81c730061907f1d4c/matangover.mypy/dmypy-d1f12cdee9d0591a310a9c4402749ab59684e6e7.log -- . --show-column-numbers --no-error-summary --no-pretty --no-color-output --config-file pyproject.toml --python-executable /home/pig208/myproject/.venv/bin/python
[69] Mypy output:
analytics/foo.py:12:1: error: Need type annotation for "test_foo" (hint: "test_foo: Dict[<type>, <type>] = ...")
```

The `files` configuration still seems to be ignored when I running mypy in command line:

```
$ mypy . --config pyproject.toml
analytics/foo.py:12: error: Need type annotation for "test_foo" (hint: "test_foo: Dict[<type>, <type>] = ...")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 15 source files)
```

(`exclude` could solve the problem but I still want to get `files` to work)

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the fact that the scripts you are checking are dependent on `analytics/foo.py`. Therefore, it is checked to determine the types in `server/**/*_some_files.py`.